# Why am I not able oneHot encode my data labels?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have an array of labels that are arranged as following:

```
['PAM4' '2']
 ['QPSK' '2']
 ['CPFSK' '0']
 ...
 ['AM-DSB' '-18']
 ['QAM64' '18']
 ['AM-DSB' '-12']]
[['PAM4' '2']
 ['QPSK' '2']
 ['CPFSK' '0']
 ...
 ['AM-DSB' '-18']
 ['QAM64' '18']
 ['AM-DSB' '-12']]
```

and I wanted to oneHot encode them using just the first column(PAM4,QPSK,CPFSK ...)
using this code:

```
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[0])

Y_test = labelencoder.fit_transform(Y_test[:, 0])
Y_test = onehotencoder.fit_transform(Y_test)
```

But I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nechi/PycharmProjects/CNN_MR_v2/cnn.py", line 30, in <module>
    Y_test = onehotencoder.fit_transform(Y_test)
  File "/home/nechi/PycharmProjects/CNN_MR_v2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py", line 509, in fit_transform
    self._handle_deprecations(X)
  File "/home/nechi/PycharmProjects/CNN_MR_v2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py", line 392, in _handle_deprecations
    n_features = X.shape[1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

when I tested the `labelencoder` result it was correct, So the issue must be from the `onehotencoder`.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LabelEncoder` is used for targets, and therefore returns only one dimension (n_samples, ).
`OneHotEncoder` is used for features, and therefore take two dimensions as input (n_samples, n_features).

You can add one dimension with `Y_test[:, None]`.

```py
Y_test = labelencoder.fit_transform(Y_test[:, 0])
Y_test = onehotencoder.fit_transform(Y_test[:, None])
```

Note however that in the latest scikit-learn version, `OneHotEncoder` can encode categorical features directly from strings, so you do not need a `LabelEncoder` (which is reserved to targets). See for instance this very complete [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer_mixed_types.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-compose-plot-column-transformer-mixed-types-py).